# Biquery, how to split a field into multiple column with a max size

Tags: google-bigquery

I have this Query

```
SELECT
  * EXCEPT( county_geom ),
  CASE
    WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(ST_ASTEXT(county_geom)) <32766 THEN county_geom
  ELSE
  NULL
END
  AS county_geom
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.utility_us.us_county_area`
```

how to split the field "county_geom" into multiple new column having the max size as 32766 ?

edit : My use case is, I do the analysis in PowerBI, there is a limitation in PowerBI is that you can only import a column that have a max string length of 32766, but later, I can join back those columns to get the original field.

Comment: can you elaborate on your use case please? most likely just splitting on size will not be sufficient. Please share more details on what it is that you are trying to achieve

Comment: done, I added edits

Comment: I'm curious. Have you considered to perform the extra processing programatically instead of recieving the results directly from BigQuery?

Comment: I am using PowerQuery to split the columns and concatenate them again in the data model, but thought a native sql will be faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested a solution using Dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE column_length int64;
DECLARE county_geom_arr_select string;

CREATE TEMP TABLE source_data AS (
SELECT * EXCEPT( county_geom ),
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(ST_ASTEXT(county_geom), r'' || REPEAT('.', 32) || '{1000}') county_geom_arr
FROM `bigquery-public-data.utility_us.us_county_area`
);

SET column_length = (SELECT max(array_length(county_geom_arr)) FROM source_data);
SET county_geom_arr_select = (SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG("county_geom_arr[SAFE_OFFSET("||offset_nr||")] as col"||offset_nr), ", ") from UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, column_length, 1)) offset_nr);

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format("""
  SELECT * EXCEPT( county_geom_arr ), %s from source_data
""", county_geom_arr_select)
```

The regex to create the array was based on [Mikhail Berlyant's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221944/mikhail-berlyant) answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try below (for BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
SELECT * EXCEPT( county_geom ),
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(ST_ASTEXT(county_geom), r'.{1000}') county_geom_arr
FROM `bigquery-public-data.utility_us.us_county_area`
```

Above splits original value to elements of size 1000 - so, then - you can join array's elements back to original value

If having size close to 32K - you can use below option

```
SELECT * EXCEPT( county_geom ),
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(ST_ASTEXT(county_geom), r'' || REPEAT('.', 32) || '{1000}') county_geom_arr
FROM `bigquery-public-data.utility_us.us_county_area`
```

Comment: it is has to be columns, I don't think PBI support array

Comment: you can UNNEST it to rows and then do pivot in EXCEL - right? let me know if this is reasonable option and you need further help in UNNEST'ed version of above

Comment: no, Excel is not involved in the workflow, is there a solution using columns please

Comment: Somehow I thought Excel is part of use-case. Anyway - I have one option in mind - will get back to it later in a day - stay tuned